# How to move value from one storage/Saved of data to another in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to fix adcolony's code to word with my point system,

Firstly -

```
Constants.h

#define kCurrencyBalance @"CurrencyBalance"

AppDelegate.m

// Get currency balance from persistent storage and update it
    NSNumber* wrappedBalance = [storage objectForKey:kCurrencyBalance];
    NSUInteger balance = wrappedBalance && [wrappedBalance isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] ? [wrappedBalance unsignedIntValue] : 0;
  balance += amount;
```

Whats happening is the data is being stored in Currency Balance if I'm not mistaken

I need the currency to go from kCurrencyBalance to the coin label called lblPts and then get saved in that amount.

This is what I've tried so far

```
[lblPts setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", nPoint]];
```

The problem is that the coins are gathering up in the storage and are not being saved in the label or nPoints...

How will I pass each new balance that goes into CurrencyBalance into the nPoint and onto the label?

If anyone has worked with Adcolony please help out, I can supply any extra code or info!

this is in PlayViewController:

```
- (void)updateCurrencyBalance {
    NSNumber* wrappedBalance = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kCurrencyBalance];
    NSUInteger balance = wrappedBalance && [wrappedBalance isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]] ? [wrappedBalance unsignedIntValue] : 0;
    [lblPts setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", balance]];
```

Its continuously gathering up data and then stores it, and after a video is watched it adds the total!

Comment: Where did nPoint come from?  Where in your code are you setting it and attempting to update the label?  The code you have shown from your appDelegate stores the value in a variable 'balance'.  Where is this defined?  How often is this code executed (which method is it in?)

Comment: nPoint is an integer, and im setting it in the PlayViewController I update the label but it seems that there are two different storages.

Comment: But where is nPoint defined? Is it an instance variable?  A local variable?  How do you assign a value from a variable in the appDelegate object to this variable in the PlayViewController object? Can you edit your question to show this code?

Comment: I've added what I believe is important to understand whats going on!

Comment: Looking at the code you added, have you added a breakpoint to this code and stepped through it?  Is the value coming back from NSUserDefaults what you expect?  Is the code even called?  Is lblPts set to an instance of a UILabel or is it nil?

Comment: Hey Not sure, But in my purchases I have the coins assigned as "cns" Im not able to do it, so I just wont put it in!